# THYMELEAF. th:each doesn't work for model attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

I am trying to display `List` of forms in my browser using Thymeleaf. this `List` is assigned to a `model` attribute

```
@ModelAttribute("groups")
List<GroupReadModel> getGroups() {
    return service.readAll(); 
}
```

And this is `GroupReadModel`:

```
public class GroupReadModel {
        private int id;
        private String description;

        public GroupReadModel() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
```

I want a form for each item in this list, so I'm using `th:each` in my template:

```
<dl th:each="existingGroup : ${groups}" th:id="${existingGroup.id}">
            <dd>
                <form method="post" th:action="@{/groups}" th:object="${existingGroup}">
                    <label>Group description
                        <input type="text" th:field="${existingGroup.description}" />    
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit" name="updateGroup" th:value="${existingGroup.id}">UPDATE</button>
                </form>
            </dd>
        </dl>
```

the problem I encountered while rendering:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "groups": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "groups" - line 63, col 44)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'existingGroup' available as request attribute
```

this is line 63: `<input type="text" th:field="${existingGroup.description}" />`   
What can I do to make this code correct?

Comment: Which line is line 63 in `groups.html` ? `th:id="${existingGroup.id}"` can't work because there is no `id` property in the `GroupReadModel` class. Also `th:value="${taskStat.index + 1}"` -> Where should that `taskStat` come from?

Comment: Sorry to make a few mistakes in my question. It should be okay now. The error is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `th:object`, you are *selecting* the object and you can use the `*{..}` syntax to use it.

Replace `th:field="${existingGroup.description}"` with `th:field="*{description}"` and `th:value="${existingGroup.id}"` with `th:value="*{id}"`:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/groups}" th:object="${existingGroup}">
  <label>Group description
    <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" />    
  </label>
  <button type="submit" name="updateGroup" th:value="*{id}">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work and throws the same error on the same line